help with homework
I was given homework on mathematical analysis, but I didn't really understand this topic. I would be grateful, even for ideas on how to solve it. It is necessary to investigate the following series for uniform convergence.In no row can we get rid of x to apply Weierstrass's theorem. So basically i don't understand what to do in such situations.
1.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\sin x\cdot e^{-n\tan x}$ $x\in (0;\pi/2)$
$\sin x\cdot e^{-n\tan x} \le e^{-n\tan x} \le e^{-nx}$, because $x \le \tan x$ but idk what to do next.
2.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x^2/n)}{x^2\cdot \sqrt{n}+1}$ $x\in (-\infty ;+\infty )$
$\frac{sin(x^2/n)}{x^2\cdot \sqrt{n}+1} \le \frac{1}{x^2\cdot \sqrt{n}+1} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $|x|\le 1$ she diverges => for $|x| \le 1$
this series does not converge uniformly
3.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x/n}\cdot cos(nx)}{x^2+n^3x}$ $x\in (0;+\infty )$
$\frac{e^{-x/n}\cdot cos(nx)}{x^2+n^3x} \le \frac{e^{-x/n}}{x^2+n^3x} \le \frac{1}{x^2+n^3x} \le \frac{1}{n^3x} \le \frac{1}{n^3}$ for $x \le 1$ she diverges
Thank you!

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem in order to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

One question per question.

First you must know something important about this series.
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$
It series converges when $|x| < 1$ and diverges when it doesn't.
One more series to know.
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^p$ coverges if $p<-1$ and diverges otherwise.
Then we compare most of the other series we encounter to series that we understand.
Comparison tests:
If we have series that we are trying to analyze $\{a_n\}$ and series that we know $\{b_n\}$
$\{a_n\}$ converges if $|a_n|<|b_n|$ for all $n>N$ and $\{b_n\}$ converges.
$\{a_n\}$ diverges if $|a_n|>|b_n|$ for all $n>N$ and $\{b_n\}$ diverges.
limit comparison tests:
if $\lim_\limits{n\to infty} \frac {a_n}{b_n} = M$ then $\{a_n\}$ converges if and only if $\{b_n\}$ converges.
Root tests, ratio tests.
if $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} |a_n|^\frac 1n < 1$ then $\{a_n\}$ converges.  If the limit is greater than 1 then the series diverges.
if $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \left| \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$ then $\{a_n\}$ converges.  If the limit is greater than 1 then the series diverges.
These tests are effectively comparison tests to the series at the top of this answer.
For each of series in the original question, which test do you want to apply?
Okay, I see that you have done some work in the time I was writing up what is above.

you have set up a comparison to $\sum e^{-nx}$ but are not sure if this series converges.

This is an example of our series $\sum x^n$ except we have an $e^{-x}$ in stead of an $x.$  It conveges if $e^{-x} < 1$  or $x>0$

I like your thought process except

$\sin \frac {x^2}{n} < \frac {x^2}{n}$ when $n$ is large.
So, we can compare:
$\frac {\sin \frac {x^2}{n}}{x^2\sqrt n + 1}x < \frac {\frac {x^2}{n}}{x^2\sqrt n}x = xn^{\frac 32}$
This compares to the p-series and indeed converges (for all x.)

The exponential factor will always dominate the polynomial factor.


These are the signs for ordinary convergence, in my opinion the signs for uniform convergence are different

These are all tests of uniform convergence.  I didn't discuss conditional convergence, although that is something that you should also look up.

In the first one, we say that |e^(-x)|<1 means the function is uniformly convergent, but I don't understand how to formally write this. Is there an official name for this feature?

It is the interval of convergence.  If $x,$ is in some interval the series converges.
